# React is overriding server-side-rendered page with placeholder markup

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, server-side-rendering

I'm currently setting up an application with React and SSR. For reasons outside of the scope of this question, I am not able to use frameworks like Next.js, Gatsby or even Create React App.

The web server is written in NestJS, and that's what I'm using to handle routing/requests. So far, what I have been to accomplish is to send all the requests to a "Catch-all" handler that maps the URL to content written to an MDX File, transforms the MDX to JSX, and concatenates the JSX with a very basic HTML template that loads React. And here's where the problem happens. As soon as I send the HTML from NestJS to the browser, the `bundle.js` file kicks-in and overrides the JSX content I'm sending it with. Essentially my question is how can I prevent this behavior?

On the react side, I have a very basic set up:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
// index.js

import React from "react";
import { hydrate } from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";
import "./styles.css";

hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```
// App.jsx
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default App;
```

On the NestJS side, essentially my Catch-All controller does this:

```js
  @Get('*')
  async getOne(@Req() req: Request): Promise<string> {
    const { url } = req;

    // this reads the file based on the URL, and transpiles MDX -> JSX -> HTML
    const content = await this.webClientService.getContentByURL(url);
    const jsx = await mdx(content);
    const mdxToString = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(jsx);

    // this reads the output HTML of my react application
    const app = await this.webClientService.getApp();

    // this replaces the empty react content, with my content.
    const output = app
      .replace('bundle.js', '/bundle.js')
      .replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${mdxToString}</div>`);

    return output;
  }
```

All of this works fine, however when I run the code, this is what happens:

[image: React overrides component]

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding what your server side code, your entry point on the client-side would normally read the initial state from a variable and rehydrate. Your `index.js` doesn't seem to be doing that.

There are many examples out there on how to do that, but I think that's your issue here.